# Are physical ETFs allowed to trade more often than what they report?

Tags: etf, rebalancing

Looking at any ETF, they often show a rebalance interval in a fact sheet. For example, [DE0006289390](https://www.ishares.com/de/privatanleger/de/produkte/251770/ishares-dow-jones-industrial-average-ucits-etf-de-fund) shows "quarterly" there.

May the managers/administrators (or however you call the people) of the ETF change the ETF more often? Do they have fixed dates when they rebalance or is there a kind of grace period / interval in which they have to do it?

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on exchange in question. Most ETF are electronic. Not sure about your question on rebalance... Are you asking do ETF rebalance the portfolio quarterly?

Comment: The managers of physical ETFs have to adjust the values they hold in order to keep the tracking error low. Some say in their fact sheets that they rebalance quarterly. I am wondering if this means that they are legally bound to do so or if they can do it more often / less often.

Comment: What's a **physical** ETF?

Comment: @RonJohn I assume it refers to an ETF that does not use derivatives to construct a synthetic portfolio tracking the index, but rather owns directly the assets. It's much better approach during financial crises to own directly the assets as derivatives have a counterparty risk.

Comment: I thought Physical ETF was related to commodities ETFs like GLD where the primary asset is bars of gold in a vault rather than gold futures.

Comment: For ETCs this is physical replication. For stock market ETFs physical just means actually owning the shares. To my knowledge, the synthetic method is rather popular over here in Europe. Lyxor has a lot of synthetic ETFs for example. The advantage of synthetic ETFs is that it allows to replicate any index, no matter how difficult to trade. For example, consider you would make an EM small cap index fund. This is a real pain to trade, especially for a smaller fund just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Rebalancing of ETF or any Mutual fund would be as per what is declared in the fact sheet.

Unless there is Gross misrepresentation, regulations don't apply

Answer (score 0):

The deadline you're referring to would be the end of each quarter, when funds release their performance data.  What you often see happening is what's called "window dressing", which occurs near the end of the quarter when funds will do what they can to make their funds look better by dumping their losers and bulking up on the ones that performed well.

Here's an article that can help address much of what your question asks and explains the concept of window dressing:

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/windowdressing.asp